# What would the input be called in to an MVC architecture?

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture, models

I am building a basic user API.

For example, the API has a model entity USER and returns a UserView that does not contain the hashed password for example back to the front end.

To create the user, the front end passes a JSON object of "USER" but missing parts such as the "createdOn" and "scope" fields that are to be fulfilled by the back end.

What do you call the "object" that is passed in to the MVC?

***{Username,Password}*** ---> Conrtoller --->Service ---> Model(Persisted) ---> View

I.e. what would you call the input? It is like the User model but missing parts that are to be filled in by the Service layer to form the completed model to persist.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no standard term for this actually.

Comment: Oh right. Well would "RequestModel" seem a fair description?

Comment: yes you can say that..

Answer (score 0):

There is not an official term.
 A fair representative name could be "Form", derived from a form in php/html.